# How to enable django form fields based on check box input?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms

This is my django dynamic form which generates field based on the given csv file column.

```
 class SetFeatureForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, project=None, *args, **kwargs):

        super(SetFeatureForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if project:
            choices = [(column,column) for column in pd.read_csv(project.file.path).columns]
            self.fields['feature'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=choices, required=True, )
            self.fields['feature'].widget.attrs['size']=len(choices)
            for _,choice  in choices:
                self.fields[choice] = forms.ChoiceField( choices=DATA_TYPE.items())
```

I have to enable all the fields based on the field 'feature' which is MultipleChoiceField. Based on the selection I have to enable the 'choice' field.
How can I do that, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking: are you asking how to render the form so that when the user selects a feature you display only the correct choice field? Or how to process the form after it's posted? In the second case, you should make all choice fields optional and you'll need to override the `clean()` method of the form to just check the one choice field that corresponds to the submitted `feature` field.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for but if you need the ability to have dynamic choices entered into the model:

models.py

```
def get_menu_choices():
    choices_tuple = []
    #do your stuff
    return choices_tuple

class ChoiceModel(models.Model):
    choices_f = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True)

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._meta.get_field('choices_f')._choices = lazy(get_menu_choices, list)()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('testapp:choicemodel_list')
```

Otherwise if you already know the headings and they are static you can follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#choices

Just make sure to modify your forms to something like:
forms.py

```
class ChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = ChoiceModel
        fields = ['choices_f']
```

btw the above dynamic solution was sourced from http://blog.yawd.eu/2011/allow-lazy-dynamic-choices-djangos-model-fields/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51942404/how-to-handle-django-dynamic-in-front-end I think this could describe about my question. Can you please take a look at it.