# How to handle Django dynamic in front end?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, django-forms

I have a Django form class which generates dynamic form fields to the front end. I want to perform operations such as enable, disable, hide, display etc.. by using java script.simply I want take control of the django dynamic form js.

This is my django form

```
class SetFeatureForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, project=None, *args, **kwargs):

        super(SetFeatureForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if project:
            choices = [(column,column) for column in pd.read_csv(project.file.path).columns]
            self.fields['feature'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=choices, required=True, )
            self.fields['feature'].widget.attrs['size']=len(choices)
            for _,choice  in choices:
                self.fields[choice] = forms.ChoiceField( choices=DATA_TYPE.items())
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Is there any error we can help you with?

Comment: You can add id,class to your form elements and then use them in javascript to perform operations you mentioned ?

Comment: @Ashish By default Django forms creates a id for each field. since it is a dynamic form I won't have a static number of field and field type(check box, drop down).